# Difficulty Finding dz/dt

Tags: derivatives

If $$z=e^xcos y$$
With
$$x^3+e^x-t^2-t=1$$
$$yt^2+y^2t-t+y=0$$
Find
$$\frac {dz}{dt}$$
When I asked my teacher for any tips he said something about differentiating both sides of the 2nd and 3nd equation. But I just can't see how this could help me or get anywhere closer to the solution. How can I find $\frac{dz}{dt}$?

Comment: What class are you taking?  Is this a single variable calculus class, or a multivariable calculus class?  What section of material is this from (at a guess, I would assume that you are just learning implicit differentiation?).

Comment: As a function of which quantities are you asked to express $dz/dt$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find $\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dt}$, we need to find the dependence of $x$ and $y$ on $t$. In particular, if we write $z = z(x(t), y(t))$, then by the chain rule,
$$\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}.$$
Differentiating the first equation wrt $t$,
$$3x^2 \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} + e^x \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} - 2t - 1 = 0 \implies \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{2t+1}{3x^2 + e^x},$$
and for the second equation,
$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt} t^2 + 2ty + 2y \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt} t + y^2 - 1 + \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt} = 0 \implies \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{1 - 2ty}{t^2 + 2yt + 1}.$$
Thus, \begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dt} = e^x \cos y \left( \frac{2t+1}{3x^2 + e^x} \right) - e^x \sin y  \left(\frac{1 - 2ty}{t^2 + 2yt + 1} \right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't realize that considering x and y as a function of t and applying the chain rule would be that useful.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $x$ and $y$ are both functions of $t$.  Differentiate the second equation, and you can solve for $dx/dt$ as a function of $x$ and $t$.  Similarly for the third to get $dy/dt$ as a function of $y$ and $t$.  Now differentiate the first equation, substitute in, and you can get $dz/dt$ as a function of $x$, $y$ and $t$.

You could actually solve for $y$ explicitly as a function of $t$ because your third equation is quadratic in $y$, but you can't get $x$ explicitly as a function of $t$ in the second equation.

Answer (score 0):

Use chain rule here: $\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$.

One should be able to find $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ from the equations provided.